# Ajax Reading from a Database Dynamically

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database

I'm developing a website/database solution which gives the administrator the option to sign into the webpage and perform actions on the database.

Currently they can add/delete/run pre-defined queries, however to **'edit'** records in a table, I would like them to specify the primary key (ID) and then have ajax read in the values associated with that record and allow them to be changed.

What's the best way to go about this? Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll probably want to use a Javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which takes care of a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

The main API methods you'll be concerned with are

1. [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to convert your form data into a string to be passed to your PHP script
2. [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to perform the Ajax call (passing in details of the data you're changing)